# Any way to update the browser list in a Web/Load Test Project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I created a Web Performance and Load Test Project in Visual Studio 2015.  I created a Load test and in the wizard it gives me a list of available browsers to simulate.  The browsers it lists are extremely old (Chrome 2, Netscape).

Anyway to update the list?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The list of browsers is taken from the files in a Visual Studio directory. For the 2013 version the directory is as follows. Similarly named directories are used for other Visual Studio versions.

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Templates\LoadTest\Browsers
```

The actual `*.browser` files contain XML and can be edited with Notepad etc. If you know the characteristics of the browser you want to simulate then it should be simple to copy and modify an existing file.

I have not seen any web page that specifies the details of the `*.browser` files. Part of their content is the "user agent string" and web searching should readily find the string for many new browsers.

Be aware that standalone web tests are run differently than those run within a load test. Standalone web tests are run as if by a default browser. Have not found any way to specify that browser. Many characteristics of the real browser may be irrelevant but the user agent string may be important. I wrote the following plugin when testing a web site for it behavior when accessed by a mobile phone or a tablet.

```
[System.ComponentModel.Description(
    "Set the user agent to a fixed value if called from a web test. For a load "
    + "test leave it alone so the value from the browser mix is used.")]
public class SetUserAgent : WebTestPlugin
{
    public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.WebTest.Context.ContainsKey("$LoadTestUserContext"))
        {
            // Leave the user agent alone, it will be set by the load test's browser mix.
        }
        else
        {
            const string UserAgent = "User-Agent";

            if (e.Request.Headers.Contains(UserAgent))
            {
                e.Request.Headers.Remove(UserAgent);
            }

            // Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 7inch.
            // e.Request.Headers.Add(UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-gb; SM-T110 Build/JDQ39) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30");

            // Sony Xeperia S, Ion.  360x640 pixels.
            e.Request.Headers.Add(UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; en-us; LT28at Build/6.1.C.1.111) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
        }
    }
}
```

It should be easy to set user agent strings for other devices.